# Cookie ou Session no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Criei uma página externa no WP, porém preciso que só quem está logado no `wp-admin` possa visualizar a página. A página externa não faz parte do WP, é uma página independente. Como eu faria essa verificação?

Verifiquei que no arquivo `pluggable.php` parece que cria um `COOKIE ( $_COOKIE[LOGGED_IN_COOKIE] )`. Então fiz dessa forma:

```
Está logado <?php $_COOKIE[LOGGED_IN_COOKIE]; ?>;
```

Mas não aparece nada.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente não use `$_COOKIE` ele não é seguro. [link relacionado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115190/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-sessions-e-cookies)

Como você disse, você esta criando um pagina independente.
A primeira coisa que você tem que ter em mente é :

> Nada que tem no outro pode ser aproveitado.

O que isso que disser? Simples, seria a mesma coisa que começar algo do zero.

Nenhuma constante, variável, classe ou método do local anterior é conhecido. Se existir, é por mera coincidência, ou porque você tem o mesmo projeto base.

Dessa forma você tem que pensar :

> Quais os meios que eu tenho para que estas aplicações se comuniquem?

Algumas são `JSON`, `cookie`, `sessão`, `Arquivo Texto`.

No seu caso o ideal seria sessão, já que se trata de um comunicação de paginas independentes no mesmo servidor.

Para fazer isso é simples, pode testar com dois arquivos mesmo.

#### file1.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = 'Guilherme Lautert';
```

#### file2.php

```
session_start();
echo isset($_SESSION['name'])?$_SESSION['name']:'Nome não definido';
```

#### Explicação

- No **file1.php** eu mandei para a sessão uma "chave" `name` com um valor.
- Note que no **file2.php** eu estou verificando (`isset`) se existe na sessão uma "chave" `name`, isso são quer disser que ela existe então eu teria que tratar para caso ela não exista.

#### Adendo

- Lembre que sessão é a mesma coisa que uma `$_GLOBAL` então se você alterar algo na sessão estará alterando em todo.